# mysql - count letters

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me how to count the letters in a string in MySQL?

For example:

```
SELECT numberOfLetters('abc123 def')
```

would return 6

By letter, I mean A-Z and a-z.

numberOfLetters is not valid SQL of course, but it illustrates what I am trying to do.

The version of MySQL that I'm using is 5.5.27

Comment: Just out of morbid curiosity, why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Do you have generic strings or do they have some specific pattern?

Comment: Also, any specific reason you need to do that in MySQL (rather than, say, PHP)

Comment: In parallel with nico, I agree that unless you have a compelling reason to do this in MySQL you might want to consider doing this in PHP, Perl, Python, or whatever is utilizing your output.  If that's not possible we could take care of this in a MySQL function, I imagine, but I'm not sure that's the best use of the DB (given MySQL's aversion for regular expressions).

Comment: The strings have no pattern, they are sentences which may contain spaces, punctuation and numbers.

Comment: I looked at user defined functions, but I can't seem to be able to create any at all - I keep getting syntax errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS numberOfLetters;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION numberOfLetters(s VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE c INT;
    DECLARE r INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE n INT DEFAULT LENGTH(s);
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;

    WHILE i <= n DO
        SET c = ASCII(SUBSTRING(s, i, 1));
        IF (c >= 65 AND c <= 90) OR (c >= 97 AND c <= 122) THEN
            SET r = r + 1;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN r;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

And then call:

```
SELECT numberOfLetters('abc123 def');
```

Answer (score 1):

Fairly off the top of my head, but I believe this will do what you need.

NOTE:  Assuming ASCII and that you're only counting a-z, A-Z.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS numberOfLetters;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION numberOfLetters (inStr CHAR(255))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE strLen INT;
    DECLARE letterCt INT;
    DECLARE pos INT;
    DECLARE curLetter CHAR(1);

    SET pos      := 0;
    SET letterCt := 0;

    SELECT LENGTH(inStr) INTO strLen;

    ctLoop: LOOP
        IF (strLen = 0) THEN
            LEAVE ctLoop;
        END IF;

        SELECT SUBSTR(inStr, strLen, 1) INTO curLetter;
        IF (ASCII(curLetter) >= 65 AND ASCII(curLetter) <= 90) OR (ASCII(curLetter) >= 97 AND ASCII(curLetter) <= 122) THEN
            SET letterCt := letterCt + 1;
        END IF;

        SET strLen := strLen - 1;
    END LOOP ctLoop;

    RETURN letterCt;
END //
DELIMITER ;

select numberOfLetters('abc123 def');
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------------+
| numberOfLetters('abc123 def') |
+-------------------------------+
|                             6 |
+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use **length()** function like that:

---

> SELECT length('abc123 def');

it returns :  **10**

Comment: Actually it's [char_length()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length), because `length()` returns the length in bytes, so multibyte characters (Unicode) count as 2.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say that this is good for MySQL, but just try it -

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE('abc123 def', ' ', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', '')
);
```

...you should add REPLACE function for each char you need to remove from counting.

Comment: @nico I said about it in my answer. Who said that it is for general use?

Comment: If he knew the string in advance then he would just count the letters and hard-code the length.

Comment: Actually works for my example, but no good if I have other characters

Comment: @nico I think his point is that if you wrap 10 replace statements (one for each digit) it would clear the numbers out of the string and only count the non-numeric characters... Unfortunately that's somewhat the opposite of what the OP wants which is to count ONLY [a-zA-Z].  Given that the OP probably isn't posing the most clear question in the world, however, as of the writing of this comment Devart's still might be the best suggestion here. ;)

Comment: @StudyOfCrying: I hear you, and this could be a punctual solution for a very specific situation. However, as a general solution to this type of problems (and, if the question is worth being on SO it has to be somehow general), I will keep the -1 because this is not a good solution. What happens in two years from now when his code stops working because some user thought of inputting a "~", which he did not include in the code? This is definitely not easy to maintain.

Comment: @Devart : Could you please look into my answer. Its your answer for one of the question. Might it can help OP. OP is getting error. Against so many replace statements, I think your answer in my link would be better.

Comment: @Fahim Parkar Oh, yes. I have have forgotten about this answer. I will check it again. Thanks, and +1.